# How do I modify this to upload multiple files?

Tags: php, arrays, post, file-upload, upload

My upload code is this. I submit the image to it with postdata. I want to make the file select box accept multiple picutes, and have it work on the backend. I can get the header location to work just fine on my own, but using an array of files has proved to be difficult, even though I've spent hours on stack overflow and google. I'd love it if somebody could show me how to do it.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $browse = $_POST["browse"];

    preg_match('/\.([a-zA-Z]+?)$/', $_FILES['userfile']['name'], $matches);

    if(in_array(strtolower($matches[1]), $accepted)) {

        if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] <= $maxsize) {

            $newname = md5_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']).'.'.$matches[1];

            $browse = $_POST["browse"];

        if ($browse == "1") {
            $filedir = 'img';
            } else if ($browse == "2") {
            $filedir = 'zega';
            } else if ($browse == "3") {
            $filedir = 'noimg';
            } else if ($browse == "4") {
            $filedir = 'adult';
            } else if ($browse == "5") {
            $filedir = 'temp';
            } else {
            $filedir = 'noimg';
        }

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],     $filedir.'/'.$newname);

            $path =  $filedir.'/'.$newname;

            if (strpos($path,'jpg') !== false){
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg ($path);
            imagejpeg ($img, $path, 100);
            imagedestroy ($img);
            } else if (strpos($path,'gif') !== false){
            $img = imagecreatefromgif ($path);
            imagegif ($img, $path, 100);
            imagedestroy ($img);
            } else if (strpos($path,'bmp') !== false){
            $img = imagecreatefrombmp ($path);
            imagebmp ($img, $path, 100);
            imagedestroy ($img);
            } 

            header("Location: index.php?p=uploaded&img=$newname");
        } else 
            header("Location: index.php?p=error&num=2");
     } else
    header("Location: index.php?p=error&num=1");
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_FILES as $key_file=>$file_info){
    //your code here instead $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] use $file_info['tmp_name']
}
```

Comment: When I use this, I get an error with this line:
    preg_match('/\.([a-zA-Z]+?)$/', $_FILES['userfile']['name'], $matches);
It is expecting an array/string and getting the other, I forgot what it was that it said because I tampered with it a lot trying to get it to work, and completely failed.

Comment: in foreach  instead of $_FILES['userfile']['name'] use file_info['name']. Just replace $_FILES['filename'] to $file_info

Answer (score 1):

i wrote a class for uploads sometimes ago.
this class has ability to upload mutiple files at the same time(such as picture .etc).

it also has other ability such as :
-if you upload mutiple files with the same name it will automatically change their name
-you can add permitted types
-set maximum size of uploaded files
...

class Upload {

```
protected $_uploaded = array();
protected $_destination_upload_folder;
//Constraint
protected $_max_upload_size = 512000;    
protected $_permitted_files = array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg');

protected $_error_messages = array();
protected $_renamed_file = false;

public function __construct($input_upload_path) {
    if(!is_dir($input_upload_path) || !is_writable($input_upload_path)){
        throw new Exception("$input_upload_path must be a valid,writable path!");
    }

    $this->_destination_upload_folder = $input_upload_path;
    $this->_uploaded = $_FILES;
}

protected function checkError($fileName, $error){
    switch ($error) {
        case 0:
            return true;
        case 1:
        case 2:
            $this->_error_messages[] = "$fileName exceeds maximum file size : "
                                       .$this->getMaxSize();
            return true;
        case 3:
            $this->_error_messages[] = "Error while uploading $fileName.please try again.";
            return false;
        case 4:
            $this->_error_messages[] = "No file selected.";
            return false;            
        default:
            $this->_error_messages[] = "System Error uploading $fileName.Please contact administrator.";
            return false;
        return false;
    }
}

protected function checkSize($fileName, $size){
    if($size == 0){
        return false;
    }else if($size > $this->_max_upload_size){
        $this->_error_messages[] = "$fileName exceeds maximum size : ".
                                    $this->_max_upload_size;
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

protected function checkType($fileName, $type){
    if(!in_array($type, $this->_permitted_files)){
        $this->_error_messages[] = 'This type of file is not allowed for uploading '
                                   .'.please upload permitted files.';
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

public function checkName($input_file_name, $overwrite)
{        
    $input_file_name_without_spaces = str_replace(' ', '_', $input_file_name);
    if($input_file_name_without_spaces != $input_file_name){
        $this->_renamed_file = true;
    }

    if(!$overwrite){
        $all_files_in_upload_directory = scandir($this->_destination_upload_folder);
        if(in_array($input_file_name_without_spaces, $all_files_in_upload_directory)){
            $dot_position = strrpos($input_file_name_without_spaces, '.');
            if($dot_position){
                $base = substr($input_file_name_without_spaces, 0, $dot_position);                    
                $extension = substr($input_file_name_without_spaces, $dot_position);
            }else{
                $base = substr($input_file_name_without_spaces);
                $extension = '';
            }
            $i = 1;
            do{
                $input_file_name_without_spaces = $base.'_'.$i++.$extension;
            }while(in_array($input_file_name_without_spaces, $all_files_in_upload_directory));
            $this->_renamed_file = true;
        }
    }        
    return $input_file_name_without_spaces;
}

protected function getMaxSize(){
    return number_format(($this->_max_upload_size)/1024, 1).'kb';
}

protected function isValidMime($types)
{
    $also_valid_mimes = array('application/pdf', 'text/plain', 'text/rtf');
    $all_valid_mimes = array_merge($this->_permitted_files, $also_valid_mimes);

    foreach($types as $type){
        if(!in_array($type, $all_valid_mimes)){
            throw new Exception("$type is not a valid permitted mime type!");
        }
    }
}

public function addPermittedType($input_type_name)
{
    $input_type_name_array = (array)$input_type_name;
    $this->isValidMime($input_type_name_array); 
    $this->_permitted_files = array_merge($this->_permitted_files, $input_type_name_array);
}

protected function processFile($fileName, $error, $size, $type, $tmp_name, $overwrite)
{
    $check_upload_error = $this->checkError($fileName, $error);
    if($check_upload_error){
        $check_uploaded_file_type = $this->checkType($fileName, $type);
        $check_uploaded_file_size = $this->checkSize($fileName, $size);

        if($check_uploaded_file_type && $check_uploaded_file_size){
            $new_uploaded_file_name = $this->checkName($fileName, $overwrite);
            $upload_result = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $this->_destination_upload_folder.$new_uploaded_file_name);
            if($upload_result){
                $messages = $new_uploaded_file_name.' uploaded successfully! <br >';
                if($this->_renamed_file){
                    $messages .= ' and renamed successfully!';
                }
                $this->_error_messages[] = $messages;
            } else {
                $this->_error_messages[] = 'Could`nt upload '.$fileName;
            }
        }
    }        
}


public function move($overwrite = FALSE){
    $file = current($this->_uploaded);
    if(is_array($file['name'])){
        foreach($file['name'] as $index => $filename){
            $this->_renamed_file = false;
            $this->processFile($filename, $file['error'][$index],
                    $file['size'][$index], $file['type'][$index], $file['tmp_name'][$index], $overwrite);
        }
    }else{
        $this->processFile($file['filename'], $file['error'], $file['size'], $file['type']
                , $file['tmp_name'], $overwrite);
    }               
}

public function getErrorMessages(){
    return $this->_error_messages;
}

public function setMaxSize($new_upload_size)
{
    if(!is_numeric($new_upload_size) || $new_upload_size <= 0){
        throw new Exception("new maximum upload size must a number!");
    }
    $this->_max_upload_size = (int)$new_upload_size;
}
```

}

```
$max_upload_size = 1024 * 1024;

if(isset($_POST['upload_button'])){
    $destination_upload_folder = 'destination of upload folder here....';
    require_once 'Upload class filename...';
    try{
        $upload = new Upload($destination_upload_folder);
        $upload->setMaxSize($max_upload_size);
        $upload->addPermittedType('application/pdf');
        $upload->move(true);
        $result = $upload->getErrorMessages();
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```